I'm looking for a movie (futuristic from the '90s I think)
I remember the first scene from the movie. There was this blonde girl walking around with a "beast", some sort of animal she used as a horse. Both of them were wearing glasses or masks, because there was something wrong with the air. On this first scene they are walking on the sand on what appeared to have been a river. On the back of the scene there is this broken bridge, probably the Brooklyn Bridge.
The only thing I remember other than this is she taking a bath with no water, in some kind of white dust.
Any ideas?

I think you might be thinking of Tank Girl (1995), based on a British comic. The titular character wears goggles and she has a mutated kangaroo boyfriend named Booga (gosh this is a weird sounding movie).
Here's a clip with the white dust shower:



The trailer, which features Tank Girl riding a Yak, both wearing a goggle+mask getup and the dust shower:


 
Plot Summary: 

In the year 2022, the Earth was struck by a comet, causing an 11-year
  drought. By 2033, a majority of the scarce water supply is being held
  in reserve by Water & Power, which uses the water to control the
  world's population. Rebecca, aka Tank Girl, is a member of a
  resistance group that steals whatever water they can find for their
  community.


OH MY GOODNESS! Thank you very much!!!! I didn't think I'll ever find it. I'm watching it today (if the Torrent God helps me.) THANKS!
